# Joe Schmo's low, oh no!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> For the last two weeks, my good friend [Joseph Schmo](http://tiny.cc/7uuzipng) has been enjoying his favorite pastime.
>   Until the incident.
>   Suddenly, everything he thought he knew was wrong.
>   Everything he asked for could no longer be provided.
>   The experience was so traumatic, he now has a least favorite number.

What is Joseph's least favorite number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the number is

> 404

The first clue is

> the URL of the hyperlink in the story is http://tiny.cc/7uuzipng. Why use a special URL to link to another stack exchange page? Let's try going to stack.imgur.com/7uuzi.png

which gives us

> [image]
>  which is the graphic on PuzzlingSE's "Page Not Found" page. To find, go to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/, followed by gibberish.

This suggests that the number is

> 404. "404" is the code for HTTP Not Found, which echoes the page where the image is found. Also, on that page, the filename of the image is in fact "404.png" (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/puzzling/img/404.png)

Comment: Good job, you got it!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the number is

> 400? In reference to HTTP Error 400

Until the incident.

> The incident could be anything that could cause a change in his internet settings, for example, switching to Comcast

Suddenly, everything he thought he knew was wrong.

> He thought he knew how to get to Puzzling.SE to partake in his favorite pastime, but all of a sudden it wasn't working.

Everything he asked for could no longer be provided.

> All he asks is to reach Puzzling.SE but it can no longer be provided due to his poor internet connection.

The experience was so traumatic, he now has a least favorite number.

> Not being able to partake in his favorite pastime is probably a traumatic experience, and the number 400 which keeps appearing in a large font, instead of the Puzzling.SE page probably leaves him resenting it.

Edit:

> Is it 4? I'm inclined to think this because four rhymes with Joe Schmo, low, and oh no, and is also the first digit in client-side http error codes.

Comment: You are on the right track, but there is something you are still missing.

Comment: Edited my answer with another guess

Comment: Let me just say that once you figure out what you're missing, you should be certain you found it.